# How to connect to the inbox of a mail like gmail or yahoo etc using a shell script?

Tags: shell

**We have a database, and we data into database from diferent sources . One source sends data through an email. I have to write a shell script in such a way , that it establishes a connection with that mail (eg: gmail) and acess the inbox of that mail. 
If possible converts the recent mails in the inbox to text format.**

Kindly help me please.. I dont know unix, but still i am given this task...

I am struggling since 2 weeks.. But I could'nt get solution..

Plss help

Comment: R u shalini kota, Pydah college of Engg & Tech. Visakhapatnam?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't write a little program in java or another language which gives you this possibility! Then you can call your program in a shell script! 
Finding a shell script with this functionality will be not so easy, if it is possible!

Answer (score 0):

Use perl or write a small java app using javamail api and invoke it using shellscript

Answer (score 0):

[Google Command Line Tool](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2010/06/introducing-google-command-line-tool.html) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Look for command line pop3 readers.  A fine example is [Getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail) which is written is python so you can have a glimpse what it's doing.

```
$ getmail --getmaildir /path/to/otherdir --rcfile getmailrc-account1
```